# AJAX based "add to cart" for AJAX loaded products list?

Tags: magento-2.1, ajax

I created a list of products from AJAX response in phtml file. In that case default AJAX "ADD TO CART" is not working. Can anyone suggest me how I can create a ajax based add to cart for products list?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have an solution for my problem. Here I am posting my solution. I hope it will help others people too.

This is my custom 'add to cart' form code, I am getting this code in my custom AJAX product listing:

```
<form id="product_addtocart_form_guide0" action="" method="post"> 
    <input name="add_to_cart_url" id="add_to_cart_url" value="http://yourDomain.com/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL2RlYWR3b29ka25pdmVzLmdyYXppdHRpLmNvbS9mYW5jeWZlZWRiYWNrL2luZGV4L2d1aWRlLw,,/product/2799/" type="hidden">
    <input id="product_id" name="product" value="2799" type="hidden">
    <input id="form_key" value="4D6nofdiNG194XG1" name="form_key" type="hidden">
    <div class="actions">
    <button title="Add to Cart" class="action tocart btn btn-default btn-cart" id="product-addtocart-button1">
        <span>Add to Cart</span></button>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is solution. I added this script in my 'phtml' file for AJAX add to cart:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).on('click', '#product-addtocart-button1', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var post_url = jQuery(this).closest("div").find("input[name='add_to_cart_url']").val();
        var data = jQuery(this).closest('div form').serialize();
        try {
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: post_url,
                dataType: 'json',
                type : 'post',
                data: data,
                success: function(data){
                    <!-- add success action here --> 
                }
            });
        } catch (e) {
        }
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Great answer. I gust added the code in Magento 2.3 CE. Works perfect.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/203283)